# Protected properties in base class missing after exluding other property

Tags: typescript

I have a generic base service for performing CRUD operations where sub classes specify a specific entity (they also specify a respective end point url).
The base class declares a protected api url that each sub class then initializes accordingly in the constructor.

Now I came across the need to actually change the signature of one of the operations for a specific entity, namely adding some parameters to `get`.

So I followed [this](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20190712-ChangeMethodSignatureInTypescriptSubclass.html) to create a type without the `get` and than provide a new signature. This works, but now the protected api url property does not exist anymore, which I don't understand.

I created a boiled down example to demonstrate this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=57&ssc=17&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4EswAXWVAM2WFgAIAVATwAdYBGGgb1xp5rGQC2sAFw0IxVEQDmeAL74ipClVqMWAJk7deTSdVFgArgIBGZOfiTIIEGgGUyANwLV2Hebis2aAIWuwAYWhrCAAeOgA+LV4aXRBSYFIAE1jUECZWUXFJMCkaAF4aAHI-CEDgmyK8bR5QSAlDRJAMOITkmiTYDNEHVGdXTE4PGPIQECwuGJi6qDh4aBApdAADABIOYgALAgh4OIzZeFGQZZwammHeEzQJ8+nwWYQFpbWN7d391kPr1FO8GPkHi8tjshhMQRC7FgAA9SGAkrZSuUQuFmGwopNeDMGk0Wmk2rAUp1uvYnC42INMVMxIYWBhiawztSeFsdns0hkCsVQeCKhBWFVzoD8MQ0b5-BCbAB1AhbECGYh+VBcsCwADuNHCEXQDJ6ZIGBQx5wA2gAFGhEGgAUWhSEMnVCAGtYAwQORxWVJWFIgAaYo-IoRAC6oiRXq1ZqDcmq2I9yOlss28sVaFDEr5MrlCqVXLDfJjfPsYK9mhhcIRca9maT2bQqI0Rvu9VQjWIzXQrVgiUJHS6mVJfXJjOizIgtLIOr7TOZrI+HPYhSKPJLgoB+BiP3Q-CEWQk0kpdyxDxgT0WK3Ws-Z6S+8B+NAAtFF1tvYLI-kLcECHsQaSZ+8u+QXPh1SLXlIS3EDen6NgsDOWMxxMdQemLPlNEKVUNQAkJ1AgzD9RgzAzlwBDWCOMYsDwEjbxuM4EPUMjxlosF6M3EoQBMIoziAA).

This is the code (errors in `SubClass2`):

```js
interface Type1 {
    name: string;
}

interface Type2 {
    price: number;
}

class Service1 {}

class BaseClass<T> {
    protected prop1: string = 'BaseClass';

    constructor(protected dep1: Service1) {}

    foo(){
        console.log(`${this.prop1}.foo`);
    }

    bar(){
        console.log(`${this.prop1}.bar`);
    }
}

class SubClass1 extends BaseClass<Type1> {
    constructor(protected dep1: Service1) {
        super(dep1);
        this.prop1 = 'SubClass1';
    }
}

type BaseClassWithoutBar = new <T>(dep1: Service1) => {
    [P in Exclude<keyof BaseClass<T>, 'bar'>]: BaseClass<T>[P];
};

const BaseClassWithoutBar: BaseClassWithoutBar = BaseClass;

class SubClass2 extends BaseClassWithoutBar<Type2> {
    constructor(protected dep1: Service1) {
        super(dep1);
        this.prop1 = 'SubClass2'; // <- Error here
    }

    bar(name: string) {
        console.log(`${this.prop1}.bar -> ${name}`); // <- Error here
    }
}

const sub1: SubClass1 = new SubClass1(new Service1());
const sub2: SubClass2 = new SubClass2(new Service1());

sub1.foo();
sub1.bar();
sub2.foo();
sub2.bar('Bob');
```

Of course I can get by this e.g. by making the property public or by creating a new method with a different name, but I would still like to know what is actually happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyof` operator does not include private and protected properties.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that, no wonder then. Thanks.